# Check if unregistered commenter is allowed to comment

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a checkbox in WP 'Discussion' settings: **Comment author must have a previously approved comment**

Is there any way to know whether current commenter is allowed to leave comments in WP through PHP? I need this to call an alert if this user left a comment and it needs to be approved by administrator before appearing on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used akismet for this:

**in functions.php:**

```
    function redirect_after_comment($location)
     {
        if(!akismet_get_user_comments_approved(null,get_comment_author_email(),get_comment_author(),get_comment_author_url())) {
            $newurl = substr($location, 0, strpos($location, "#comment"));
            return $newurl . '?approved=f';
        }
        else return $location;
    }
```

**in output:**

```
if($_GET[ 'approved' ] == 'f') {
        echo '<script>alert("Thanks, your comment will appear soon.")</script>';
    }
```